# Create new data frame with column names as row names, and values from one column as new column names

Tags: r

I'm new to R, and I'm trying to create a new data frame from an existing data frame. I want one of the column's values to be the new column headers, I want the rest of the existing column headers to be row names, and I want the values of each to be filled in. I have searched and tried many things, but I cant seem to figure it out.

Here is a small subset of my data...The original data has about 25 columns and 5000 rows.

df1 looks like this:

```
Station    month    year   rise   set    hrday
1            1      2016   334    1042   X1.134
2            3      2016   348    1053   X14.22
3            7      2016   242    1153   X23.233
4            2      2017   445    962    X10.753
```

I want the new df to have column headers that are the values from "hrday", and for the rest of the df1 column headers to be row names. It should look like this:

```
           X1.134    X14.22     X23.233    X10.753
year       2016      2016       2016       2017
month      1         3          7          2
rise       334       348        242        445       
set        1042      1053       1153       962
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `t()`, the transpose function? If yes, please edit the question with the actual code you've tried and say what went wrong.

Comment: Also add your data (even a sample) so people can work with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using base t() and tidyverse + magrittr

```
k <- tibble(Station = 1:4,
       year = c(2016,2016,2016,2017),
       month = c(1,3,7,2),
       rise = c(334,348,242,445),
       set = c(1042,1053,1153,962),
       hrday = c("X1.134","X14.22", "X23.233","X10.753"))


new_df <- k %>% select(-Station,-hrday) %>% t() %>% as_tibble() %>%
  magrittr::set_colnames(c(k$hrday)) %>%
  mutate(var =subset(colnames(k),!colnames(k) %in% c("hrday","Station"))) %>%
  dplyr::select(var, X1.134:X10.753)

new_df
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help.